# How to prevent manual entry in ui:inputDate

Tags: lightning, date, ui, inputdate

I have used `<ui:inputDate>` for entering date as follows:

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="ValidFrom" label="Valid From" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.ValidFrom}"  displayDatePicker="true" required="true" keypress="{!c.validateDate}"/>
```

When I use `disabled="true"`, the datepicker option is not visible.

I just want to prevent user entering date manually.

I tried using **event.preventDefault()** but it did not stop the user to enter value manually. The below is the code for preventDefault.

```
validateDate : function(component, event, helper){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

How to prevent user manually entering data in the ui:inputDate box? But the datepicker should be available to choose the date.

Comment: Your post doesn't contain a question.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have updated the question. Does it now sounds like a question now ;)

Comment: Instead of disabling it, you may do something with the `change` event of ui:inputDate, like you can nullify the selection may be.

Comment: @SantanuHalder ya nullify is possible. But I just want to know how it preventDefault() works in Salesforce Lightning. Any Idea?

Answer (score 5):

Well, not the change event, but the select event worked for me.

You can nullify the selection user makes in the handler of select event of ui:inputDate.

```
nullify : function(comp, ev, hel)
{
    var dp = comp.find('ValidFrom');
    dp.set('v.value', '');
}
```

Add the select event on `ui:inputDate`,

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="ValidFrom" label="Valid From" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" select="{!c.nullify}" keyup="{!c.nullify}" keypress="{!c.nullify}" updateOn="keypress, keyup" displayDatePicker="true" required="true" />
```

`keyup & keypress` combined will restrict users to stop typing anything in the box, even if he/she long presses a key. Also notice the `updateOn` attribute of the element.

Nullifying is just an option, you can show an error or warning to user as well.

Comment: But it gives an option to user to manually enter values. So that the value may not be a date.

Comment: That can be restricted using the `keyup` event, but I am more intrigued with usage of preventDefaults() function of jQuery, trying to fit that into this situation.

Comment: Kindly update the answer with keyup event. Its working good for me. Good one though. I will upvote it.

Comment: The answer is updated with keyup event.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer. But one issue in keyup is that when you long press a key, its not working @Santanu

Comment: Updated with explanation! :)

Comment: select event should be removed, since it prevent the basic datepicker selection , other than that it does do the trick